# Icorect battery stats Wh instead mAh

Tags: power-management, battery

I am looking for changes in formulas. which read info from battery. and cant find solution.

native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               PANASONIC
  model:                PABAS024
\\
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging

```
warning-level:       none
energy:              1,466 Wh
energy-empty:        0 Wh
energy-full:         5,091 Wh
energy-full-design:  5,616 Wh
energy-rate:         65,285 W
voltage:             10,793 V
time to full:        3,3 minutes
percentage:          28%
capacity:            90,6517%
technology:          lithium-ion
icon-name:          'battery-low-charging-symbolic'
```

the battery has 10.8v 5.4Ah = 62Wh
so energy of bat is displaying as Wh but should be mAh.
or better current value of energy need to multiply on curent voltage!
Multiply values on 10 be enough for me.

Comment: As a physicist, I have to agree with the current design. Watt-hours is a measure of energy, but Ampere-hours is not. If you want to do the math yourself, calculate a % full and multiply that by the nominal 5400 mAh.

Comment: @MSalters I think the point is that the battery *is* 5616 mAh, and that it's showing wrong units. A 5 Wh battery for a laptop doesn't really make sense. A 65 Wh battery however makes sense.